# See what package code is trying to be compiled in Jenkins

Tags: ros, jenkins, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to see what code is trying to be compiled for a recently released package in Jenkins? This is a comment from another question but I thought that this deserves its own thread, and that it is relevant for other people because, for instance, someone might have uploaded code from the wrong repository branch, etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208112/see-what-package-code-is-trying-to-be-compiled-in-jenkins/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2015-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find the information by foing through the following steps:

- go to the package wiki page, e.g. http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp
- go to the Jenkins sourcedeb job (link on the right side), e.g. http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-roscpp_sourcedeb/
- go to the console output of the latest build, e.g. http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-roscpp_sourcedeb/15/console
- in the beginning of the log you will find the branch from where the code is pulled:

`Note: checking out 'debian/ros-indigo-roscpp_1.11.12-0_saucy'.`

- at the end of the log you will find a reference to the release / GBP repository

`gbp-clone https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release.git`

The README In the release repository will state the exact version tag as well as the upstream repository where the code for that branch is coming from, e.g. https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/blob/master/README.md

As a shortcut you can always look at the ROS distribution file (https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/b2b035245c25243d44e03da8130510952a1143e8/indigo/distribution.yaml#L6898) but that information might have changes recently so you might not see the correct information for the last build there.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-04-30**:
Thanks! According to the ROS distribution file, it is using the correct branch of my repository. However, where does it show which branch is used within http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-handle-detector_binarydeb_saucy_amd64/8/console?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-04-30**:
The binary job builds the code from the sourcedeb (which you can download from the apt-repo). If you want to know about the upstream code go to the corresponding source job (http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-handle-detector_sourcedeb/) and follow my comments from the answer.